# Outlook Web App add in Dialog Api messageParent not working

Tags: outlook-addin, office-js, outlook-web-addins

I am developing a Outlook add in and was checking out the authentication flow (Microsoft login) for my app. I tried using the dialog api to achieve this but was not able to pass message from the dialog to the task pane after successful sign in.

index.js:

```
var fullUrl = 'https://localhost:3000/src/templates/auth.html'
Office.context.ui.displayDialogAsync(fullUrl,
{height: 40, width: 40}, function (result) {
        console.log("Dialog has initialized. Wiring up events");
        _dlg = result.value;
        console.log(result.status);
        _dlg.addEventHandler(Office.EventType.DialogMessageReceived, function(responseMessage){ console.log(responseMessage);});
    });
```

Dialog box:

```
Office.initialize = function (reason) {
    $(document).ready(function () {
        Office.context.ui.messageParent("Message 1");
    }
}
```

In the dialog console I get this,

> outlook-web-16.01.debug.js:4587 Failed to execute 'postMessage' on
>   'DOMWindow': The target origin provided ('https://outlook.live.com')
>   does not match the recipient window's origin
>   ('https://localhost:3000').

Any idea what could be the problem?

Comment: In your Manifest, for you list of <Appdomains> do all the entries have a http:// or https:// in the list?

Comment: this is my app domain listing in manifest, `<AppDomains>
    <AppDomain>https://localhost:3000</AppDomain>
  </AppDomains>`

Comment: Try to use `Microsoft.Office.WebExtension.EventType.DialogMessageReceived` instead of `Office.EventType.DialogMessageReceived`

Comment: Does the event not fire? or is the alert ignorable?

Comment: Yes got it working. The alert can be ignored. I solved the issue by adding https://outlook.live.com in the AppDomains

Comment: @AntoJoy could you please post that as an answer, and accept it, to help others who read thsi qusion in future? Thanks