# Failed to execute 'postMessage' on 'DOMWindow': The target origin provided ('https://outlook.office.com') does not match the recipient window's origin

Tags: angularjs, cors, outlook-web-addins

The following is the start of a file form a working MS Outlook web add-in.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge" />
  <title></title>
  <script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.9.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

  <script src="https://appsforoffice.microsoft.com/lib/1/hosted/office.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://appsforoffice.microsoft.com/fabric/1.0/fabric.min.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://appsforoffice.microsoft.com/fabric/1.0/fabric.components.min.css" />

  <script src="../../Assets/Scripts/jquery.fabric.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

  <link href="../../App.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  <script src="../../App.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

  <script src="Demo.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
```

However, the demo is using JQuery, and I want to replace it with an existing AngularJs, modified to be a web add-in.

My file starts

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />  
    <script src="https://appsforoffice.microsoft.com/lib/1/hosted/office.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 
    <script src="MyDialogView.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 
  <title>MyApp</title>
</head>
```

and gives the following consiole error:

> Failed to execute 'postMessage' on 'DOMWindow': 
>   The target origin provided ('https://outlook.office.com') does not match the recipient window's origin ('https://localhost').

Which looks like a CORS problem. But why did I not get it from the file above, which is in the same directory on localhost?

I can't post the entire app, but I am hoping that this strikes a chord in someone's memory ... What am I doing wrongly?

---

[Update] unlike some similar questions, there are no iframes involved. Also, adding `<AppDomain>https://outlook.office.com</AppDomain>` did not help (but why should it, when the page I copied from had no problems?)

Comment: Check out [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53505354/outlook-web-app-add-in-dialog-api-messageparent-not-working) issue could be related to AppDomain.

Comment: Thanks, very much, Suresh. I tried it, and updated my question. It didn't work, and I was careful to clear the browser cache and reload the manifest :-(

Comment: One more thing to try, if you are facing this issue in Outlook for Windows. Set compatibility to *IE=Edge*, seems like there are browser compatibility issues with [postMessage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage#Browser_compatibility)

Comment: why you says _there are no iframes involved_? How you give to the users access to their accounts in your app?

Comment: I am creating an Outlook Add-in. No special login required - or am I missing something?

Comment: No it's just to know a little bit more. Have you manually bootstrapped your angular app?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must manually bootstrap your AngularJs app because **Office.js** and **AngularJS** seem to have problems to live together. Try to initilize AngularJs manually with  `angular.bootstrap()`, within the `Office.initialize()` function. When you bootstrap AngularJs manually pay attention to not use `ng-app="myApp"` in index.html.

I.e.

```
Office.initialize = function () {
   $(document).ready(function () { // If you want jQuery too
      angular.bootstrap(document, ['myApp'])
   });
}
var app = angular.module('myApp', [// Other config...]);
// Your app config and code
```

**EDIT:**

if you don't want jQuery

```
Office.initialize = function () {
   angular.element(document).ready(function () {
      angular.bootstrap(document, ['myApp'])
   });
}
```

Or even more if your **app.js** is at the bottom of the html just near the `</body>` you can simply use `angular.bootstrap(document, ['myApp'])` because the DOM has already loaded.

Comment: If I don't want jQuery, I just remove that `$(document).ready`? If so, how do I wait until the page is loaded before starting my Angular app?

Comment: @Mawg you can use the options described above: 1) use the `jQlite` way like the AngularJs Doc `angular.element(document).ready ` and AngularJs wait the dom has loaded for you or 2) put your script at bottom of the page and use just `angular.bootstrap(document, ['myApp'])`

Comment: Thanks, Emanuele I did not have time to try yesterday, but will have time this afternoon and all weekend. If this works, expect more than 50 bonus points :-)

Comment: I hope so! Thanks

Comment: Thanks for that. I can award another bounty in 23 hours & I will. Your answer certainly looks correct, but my code which worked last weekend no longer works (and the errors look like MS, not me).   I am frustrated and ready to give up. I think that my best chance is to find a demo which I can use as a base. See my question at https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/50753/seeking-sample-ms-outlook-web-add-in-no-visual-studio

Comment: Could you please email me at  needangularjshelp@gmail.com  Thank you very much

Comment: @Mawg to accept the answer. I'm not happy if you don't have solved your problem. I'll write an email soon. I've seen your question on stackexchange I'll try to help on it.